# How to add an object to an array using data from user input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, user-input

I am building a recipe app that allows a user to add custom recipes and then display them.

I am able to add one recipe just fine, but when I add a second recipe, it changes the first one to have the same data as the second.

[image: Screenshot of Recipe App Issue]

The initial state of the list of recipes is set as an empty array:

```
recipeList: [],
  newRecipe: {
    title: '',
    source: '',
    id: ''
```

Every time I hit a submit Recipe button, I want to be able to add a new recipe to the array and display it as a thumbnail (see screenshot above). The new recipe is in the form of an object, and as seen above, the initial state of the new recipe object is set to empty. So essentially I want to be able to put new user input into the new recipe object, add it to the empty array, and display the entire array as recipe thumbnails.

In the React Dev Tools, I see both recipes in the array, so I know they are being added. But for some reason they are not being displayed correctly.

[image: Screenshot of Array Items in Dev Tools]

Upon submission, each item in the array is mapped over and returned as a thumbnail:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />

      <div className='app-body'>

      {this.state.recipeList.map((recipe) => (

          <RecipeCardThumbnail
          key={this.state.id}
          title={this.state.title}
          source={this.state.source}
          />
        ))}
```

So it could be a problem with the map() method as it seems it is not mapping through the correct array.

This is the function that fires when I submit a form to add a new recipe:

```
handleSubmitNewRecipe = e => {
e.preventDefault();
this.handleAddNewRecipe(this.state.title, this.state.source, this.state.id);
```

};

And here's the function for adding a new recipe:

```
handleAddNewRecipe = (title, source) => {

const newRecipe = {
  title: title,
  source: source,
  id: (Math.floor(Math.random()* 1000))
}
  this.setState({recipeList: [...this.state.recipeList, newRecipe] });
  console.log(this.state.recipeList)
};
```

When the array is mapped over, it returns a component called`<RecipeCardThumbnail />`. Here is the code for that component:

```
return (
    <div className="card select thumbnail-card">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{this.props.title}</h5>
        <h6 className='card-subtitle text-muted'>{this.props.source}</h6>
        <ul className="qty-details">
          <li >{this.props.servings}</li>
          <li >{this.props.prepTime}</li>
          <li >{this.props.cookTime}</li>
          <li >{this.props.totalTime}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

In addition to each item not being displayed, I also get an error saying that each child needs a unique key. I thought that the id that I have works as a key.

Not sure if this is enough code, but you can view the entire code here: [Recipe App on Github](https://github.com/LauraE91/Recipe-App)

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it seems you should be using properties of `recipe` here, not `this.state`.

So this:

```js
{this.state.recipeList.map((recipe) => (
  <RecipeCardThumbnail
    key={recipe.id}
    title={recipe.title}
    source={recipe.source}
  />
))}
```

Instead of this:

```js
{this.state.recipeList.map((recipe) => (
  <RecipeCardThumbnail
    key={this.state.id}
    title={this.state.title}
    source={this.state.source}
  />
))}
```